# Disabling full screen mode in Xamarin forms Android by using SetImeOptions NoExtractUi or NoFullscreen does not work, how to work around this?

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, autosuggest

I am working on Xamarin forms app, that uses [AutoSuggestBox](https://github.com/dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls/tree/main/AutoSuggestBox).

On iOS in landscape mode, it works ok, however on Android when used in landscape mode it hides all the suggested options under the keyboard, due to full-screen mode.

I [have tried using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/entry-ime-options) `android:Entry.ImeOptions="NoExtractUi"` on AutosuggestBox but it didn't work for me, since the underlying Entry is not exposed so I tried to implement this mechanism in isolation.

I then added a test Entry control on the view to see if it would work. However, that fails to work too.

my xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="StruebyPhotoApp.MobileApp.Views.NewItemPage"
         xmlns:asb="clr-namespace:dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox"
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">

    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="3" Padding="15">
        <Entry android:Entry.ImeOptions="NoExtractUi" x:Name="TestText" />
```

To doubledown I have also added in the constructor

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
 
public NewItemPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        TestText.On<Android>().SetImeOptions(ImeFlags.NoExtractUi);
}
```

I have also tried changing `NoExtractUi` to `NoFullscreen`  and using
`TestText.On<Android>().SetImeOptions(ImeFlags.NoExtractUi|ImeFlags.NoFullscreen);`

and I am still getting this on `Android 10`

[image]

Comment: Lets start with getting the `Entry` case to work. You need to get either the Entry itself, or the StackLayout, to only use "as much vertical space as needed", starting at top of screen. I haven't done this coding in a while, but iirc, there is some combination of vertical options on stacklayout and/or the item, that will accomplish this. Might have to also explicitly set HeightRequest on the item.

Comment: I believe my company encountered cases where we gave up doing it "right", and somehow measured the height of the keyboard, and adjusted the height (or bottom margin) of the container correspondingly. Then undid that when keyboard went away. But that was two years ago - Hopefully won't come to that for you!

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius You can also find this problem at [SetImeOptions(ImeFlags.NoFullscreen) does not prevent full screen](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7623), it seems a not fixed problem.